# I've created an imageButton keyboard. How can I make this the keyboard that pops up when I click an editText instead of the main phone keyboard?

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

This keyboard only has the keys that the app can use, so I didn't want the phone keyboard to pop up to show all the unnecessary characters. Inside of a relative layout I have a linear layout which contains the imageButtons. It's going to stay on the app, so it can't go away like normal keyboard. Here is my xml:

**What I'm trying to get:** When the user clicks on the EditText box, I don't want the phone's keyboard to pop up, I just want to be able to edit the text using imageButtons. Thanks!

I understand I'm going to have to create an onclicklistener for each button. Is there an easier way of achieving this result? Thanks for the help.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_button_keyboard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_a"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_a"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_b"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_b"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_c"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_c"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_d"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_d"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_e"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_e"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_f"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_f"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://www.infiniterecursion.us/2011/02/android-activity-custom-keyboard.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html):

> KeyboardView kbd = new KeyboardView(context);
>
> kbd.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this, R.xml.custom));
>
> kbd.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener() {
>
> }

now you have kbd which is a normal view.

The nice thing about this is that R.xml.custom refers to /res/xml/custom.xml, which defines in xml the layout of the keyboard.